# Munin plugins with 2 lines

Tags: munin, graph

I need munin plugin with 2 lines in/out.

What args i must put in my plugin like this graph view:

I need to lines and zero line.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Read through the [HowtoWritePlugins](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins) specifically the network interface plugins section.